# Show/Hide DIV container on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Expected logic:**

On mouse over main-navigation button, show - "advantage" Div container.

If user mouse over on "advantage" Div container, still show this container and allow user to click.

On mouse out of "Button" & "advantage" container - hide "advantage" Div container.

**Present Behaviour:**

On mouse over main-navigation button, show - "advantage" Div container.

If user mouse out of "Button", "advantage" container fade out & fade in. User cant able to click.

Not sure, which logic is missed out. **If user on "advantage" container, it should not hide or fadeout.**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-navigation">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button">Button</a>
</div>

<div class="advantage">
  <div class="content">
    <p>demo content to load <a href="http://www.google.com">test</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.main-navigation .button').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('.advantage).fadeIn(400);
});

$('.main-navigation .button').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('.advantage).fadeOut(800);
}).find("button, a").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Comment: The main problem is that the mouse definitely leaves the button when moves to the `.advantage` so it will hide the div (js code, line 2). One bit more complex solution could be to check within the `mouseleave` if the mouse is over the `.addvanatage` or not and prevent the fadeOut in this case.

Comment: The main problem is that you're trying to solve a css problem with javascript.
See here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div class="fadebox">
            <div class="main-navigation">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button">Button</a>
            </div>
            <div class="advantage" style="display: none;">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>demo content to load <a href="http://www.google.com">test</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 $('.main-navigation .button').on('mouseover', function (e) {
                $('.advantage').fadeIn();
                $('.advantage').find("button, a").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });`enter code here`
            });
            $('.fadebox').on('mouseleave', function () {
                $('.advantage').fadeOut();
            })
```

Check this solution.it will work fine as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your html button style class is given with missing double quotes (").

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-navigation">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button">Button</a>
</div>
<div class="advantage">
    <div class="content">
       <p>demo content to load <a href="http://www.google.com">test</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also use jquery for mouse actions (.mouseover() and .mouseleave()) as shown below:

**JS:**

```
$(".main-navigation .button").mouseover(function(){
 $('.advantage').fadeIn(400);
}); 
$(".main-navigation .button").mouseleave(function(){
    $('.advantage').fadeOut(800);
}).find("button, a").on("click", function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. But, this is not the issue here pls. While i type i missed out " for button class.